# Create a web service in java to receive outbound message in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

How to create a webservices in java or .net to receive the outbound message from salesforce and just print the Id of the record? Your help pls.

Comment: I have no idea. I dont know how to start.

Comment: Well you're unlikely to get an answer here with this type of question. Why don't you try breaking down the problem. First just learn to create a web service in java. Find a tutorial and get a basic web service up and running. Then you can try to tackle the SalesForce integration.

Comment: I found [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18625/using-java-and-spring-to-integrate-with-salesforce-rest-apis) when searching for same issue.